# Search MS Word binary file for specific content

Tags: vb.net, file, search, binary, ms-word

I have some .doc binary files stored in my database and i would like to now search them all (without converting them to .doc) to see which one contains the word "hello" for instance.

Is there any way to do this search in the binary file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without a lot of pain, as far as I can tell. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOC_%28computing%29), Microsoft has within the past few years finally released the .doc specification. So you could create a parser based on the spec if you have the time, assuming all of your documents are in the same version of the .doc format.

Of course you could just search for the text you're looking for amid all the binary data, on the assumption that the actual text is stored as plain text. But even if that assumption were true, how could you be sure that the plain text you found was the actual document text, and not some of the document meta data that's also stored in plain text? And there's always the off chance that the binary data will match your text pattern.

If the Word libraries are available to you, I would go that route. If not, a homegrown parser may be your least bad option.

Comment: The Word libraries are not an option, as I said in the comment above I already replace them with Aspose for another tasks that I need to accomplish. The problems you described when searching directly the binary are exactly the ones I identified and the reaseon i posted here, I'm starting to think that i really can't search directly in the binary because of the MS Word encryption. You said MS has released information on how Word encrypts its documents? Have you ever worked with it?

Comment: No, I never have worked with the .doc format, I just read about it. I did briefly consider working with RTF directly one time as a backdoor way of using Word functionality, and decided against it because the spec was too complex to work on within my project timeframe. I would assume the .doc spec is considerably more complex. I don't know that it's actually *encrypted*, though. More likely the binary data follows some kind of encoding scheme that you could parse if you had the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You could go down the route of using commercial tools.  [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) can load a document from a stream and has all sorts of methods for finding text within the document.

If you have the stream from the DB, then you code would look like this:

```
Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(streamObjectFromDatabase);

if (doc.GetText().ToLower().Contains("hello world"))
  MessageBox.Show("Hello World exists");
```

Note:  The benefit of this tool is that it does not require Word objects to be installed and it can work with streams in memory.

Comment: I am indeed working with Aspose Words in other tasks for the same project and I am aware that I can make the job that way. The only problem is that I have lots and lots of .doc files. Even counting the fact that with Aspose I can open and search one by one more quickly than with the MS Word Object, it still is not a pretty way to do it. What I wanted was to search directly in the binary file, without having to open it in any way.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to build a search functionality across documents?  You could extract the text one time and store that in a text field in the database and then search that text field.